# add a static row to ssrs query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am wondering if there is a way to add a fixed/ static row to a SSRS query depending if the row exist.

let's say I have the table below:

Header1 | Header2

Value1   | Value2

I would like to know how can I add an additional row called Value under Header1 with Header2 having 0  as value if Header1 does not already contain a row called Value?

PS: I cannot use SQL keyword CONTAINS 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use union to include a static row.

```
if not exists (select 1 from Table where Header1='Value')
BEGIN
select Header1, Header2
From Table
Union
Value as 'Header1',0 as 'Header2'
END
```

Comment: @CoFran , please mark as answer if this is what you are looking for. Thanks!